# SignalR-How to authenticate .Net console app with server that uses OpenID Connect

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have an existing server that uses Azure AD. I want to add SignalR Hub and connect to that hub from a console app. Yet it failed (detailed error below).

From Fiddler I can see that I receive the access token successfully but the next request is redirected to the login page when HubConnection tries to start.

I have followed instruction [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization#header) and used both `connection.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)` and `connection.Headers.Add("Bearer", accessToken)`

What is the correct way to secure and integrate SignalR in this situation?

Client code I tried

```
        HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(webEndpoint);
        string accessToken = GetAccessToken().Result;
        connection.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        connection.Headers.Add("Bearer", accessToken);
        IHubProxy webJobHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("JobHub");

        connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                log.FatalException("Error start SignalR connection", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
            }
            else
            {
                log.Info("SignalR connection established");
            }
        }).Wait();
    ...

    public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
        // ADAL includes an in memory cache, so this call will only send a message to the server if the cached token is expired.
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, AppKey);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AppIdUri, clientCredential);
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Server code:

```
[Authorize]
public class JobHub : Hub
{
...
}
```

Existing auth server code:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    ...
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ClientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    ...
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Actual exception, basically it is supposed to receive a json but get redirected to the login page

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.TransportHelper.<>c.<GetNegotiationResponse>b__0_1(String raw)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass31_0`2.<Then>b__0(Task`1 t)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RunTask>b__0(Task`1 t)
```